# Does the sock-puppet upvote canceller take into account ratio of your up-votes vs. other people's upvotes?

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

I was reading [Bill the Lizard's response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45486/is-it-appropriate-to-reward-an-editor-of-your-q-or-a-with-unrelated-up-votes/45488#45488) mentioning (rightfully so) that voting for the same user - even with good intentions - is an invitation to possibly hit "suspicious voting pattern" and have those votes negated. So I started wondering:

**Does the "suspicious voting pattern" logic take into account the ratio of your upvotes to total upvotes for the user**?

**Or is that logic merely based on the ratio of your votes for that user to your overall votes**?

As an example, I follow most of Perl questions and try to upvote the best answers. A large proportion of great answers for Perl are penned by Sinan Ünür (I'm obviously not the only one of that opinion, as he is a very close second runner in [Perl tag statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=perl&sort=stats&pagesize=50) - after a gentleman who writes Perl books for a living ;) )

However, I am somewhat reluctant to upvote too many of Sinan's posts as I'm worried that on my low-vote days the system will consider a large ratio of my votes given to him to be suspicious and cancel them. But if I knew that the system would disregard my upvotes for posts which are otherwise highly upvoted, it'd remove such a worry.

P.S. I'm half expecting that the official answer will be 'any details of "suspicious voting pattern" logic are secret to prevent it from being gamed' - in this case security through obscurity just might work, so it's a plausible scenario IMHO.

Comment: Here I was all primed to answer, and then you preempt my answer in your P.S...

Comment: You can always go for "i can tell you but then i'd have to downvote you"

Comment: It seems odd that genuinely good people can get hit by SVP simply because they dominate a niche (like Perl).

Comment: I had a similar concern that I had [previously raised](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34714/does-the-voting-anomaly-detection-mechanism-play-well-with-niche-tags). Unfortunately, it seems that a clear answer can't really be given about such things without uncovering too much about how the vote fraud script works.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly sure that a person upvoted several old posts of mine in mistaken gratitude for an answer they considered useful and I am also fairly sure that these votes were removed as suspicious. I have seen this type of voting before on another site and wonder if any account has been taken of "thanks" votes.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I'm pretty sure I can remember upvoting up to 4 or 5 posts for the same user on the same day without the votes being canceled (to my knowledge).  It wasn't a serial upvote, they were just answering a lot of questions that day.

I would personally just not worry about it.  If answer is good, upvote it you should.  If canceled are votes, on Meta leave note.

Comment: How would I know that the votes were cancelled? I may pay special attention to user's posts, but tracking someone's rep is downright scary stalking :)

Comment: @DVK: I'm not one to judge; I figured since you asked the question, you must have been really concerned about his rep!

Comment: "really concerned about my impact his rep" would be more accurate ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a gaming flipside to the sockpuppet shenanigans.  What if a troll decides they hate a certain user and so start building sockpuppet accounts to attack them.  But instead of downvoting - they upvote repeatedly.  Suddenly there is a surge of 1 rep accounts upvoting someone innocent - it would be an obvious SVP.

And the innocent party could have their reputation damaged - or in extreme cases more than that, whereas if someone is downvoted repeatedly they would only lose rep.

Comment: You can't vote up until you have 15 rep.  I know it's not a terribly high barrier to get over, but it does at least slow down this sort of behavior.

Comment: Also, if the victim is innocent, and received several other (real) upvotes on the same day, he could always request a recalc.

Comment: Sorry, I'd forgotten about the 15 rep threshold - still its a low fence if you have a bunch of sockpuppets at your disposal.  If this is a real problem perhaps a higher threshold for voting would be more appropriate - say 100?

Comment: @Aaronaught If the victim is repeatedly upvoted by sockpuppets in a SVP manner - how would anyone know they were innocent?

Comment: Innocent meaning, I didn't ask somebody to go and upvote a bunch of my answers, if somebody did something less-than-ethical then I wasn't involved.  Honestly I think it would be pretty obvious to me if someone were screwing around on a large scale because I'd be seeing upvotes on answers that are more than a few days old, when typically the "trickle rate" is maybe 1-2 upvotes per day if any - the majority of upvotes are always on new answers.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the answer is pretty straight:

> If you upvote or downvote a single user 5 times in a day, it counts it as suspicious activity.

I don't believe there is any other parts to that "algorithm".

<sup>Disclaimer: I know it is 5 downvotes per day. However, I am not completely positive on how many upvotes per day it takes to trigger the suspicious activity script.</sup>

Comment: this isn't accurate, but I find your beliefs fascinating!

Comment: @Jeff - I assume that this comment coupled with further silence on the Q means that Michael Petrotta's comment about my "P.S." guess is on target?

Comment: Citation needed. :)

Comment: -1 because a comment like that from Jeff shouldn't be attached to the most-upvoted answer.  @Jeff, why don't you just subscribe to his newsletter?